# How to update an object in an array using onChange method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I am creating the list from the skidList array and handling copy and delete operation on each skid as well as on the change of `InputNumber`(quantity) I am calling `updateProductQuantity` method which updates the quantity of the product in that skid. 
 However, Instead of updating quantity for the product for a particular skid, it updates quantity for all the skids in the array list.

[image]

```
    const CreateNewTab = () => {
           const [skidList, setSkidList] = useState([]);
           const [productNameMap, setproductNameMap] = useState({});
           
          useEffect(()=> {
             let skidList=[];
            let newSkid = {};
            newSkid["2"] = "0";
            newSkid["3"] = "0";
            newSkid["4"] = "0";
            skidList.push(newSkid);
            setSkidList([...skidList]);
            let productNameMap={};
            productNameMap["2"]="PEN";
            productNameMap["3"]="PENCIL";
            productNameMap["4"]="ERASER";
            setproductNameMap({...productNameMap});
           }, [])   
    
     const updateProductQuantity = (skid, key, newQuantity, index) => {
                console.log("Inside update Skid Quantity Index= " + index);
                skid[key] = newQuantity;
                let newSkidList = skidList;
                newSkidList.splice(index, 1, skid);
                console.log(newSkidList);
                setSkidList([...newSkidList]);
            }
    
            const deleteSkid = (index) => {
                console.log(index);
                let newSkidList = skidList;
                newSkidList.splice(index, 1);
                console.log("Skid deleted from: "+newSkidList);
                setSkidList([...newSkidList]);
            }
            const insertSkid = (skid) => {
                let newSkidList = skidList;
                newSkidList.push(skid);
                console.log("New Skid Inserted: "+newSkidList);
                setSkidList([...newSkidList]); 
          };    
    return(
      <div>
        {skidList.flatMap((skid, index) => (
                 <div style={{ marginRight: "0", paddingRight:"0" }}>
                       <Row style={{ margin: "0" , padding:"0"}}>
                           <Col span={19} >
                               {Object.keys(skid).map((key) =>(     
                                  <Row>
                                      <Col span={16}>
                                          <h6>{productNameMap[key.toString()]}</h6>
                                      </Col>
                                      <Col span={8}>
                                        <InputNumber
                                            min={0}
                                            defaultValue={skid[key]}
                                            rules={[{
                                                      required: true,
                                                      message: "Please input quantity!"
                                                  }]}
                                            onChange={(newQuantity) => {updateProductQuantity(skid,key,newQuantity,index)}}
                                        />
                                      </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                  ))}
                                </Col>
                                <Col span={5} >
                                   <Row>
                                     <Col span={12}>
                                       <Button type="primary" icon={<CopyOutlined />} size="large" shape="circle" onClick={() => insertSkid(skid)} />
                                     </Col>
                                     <Col spna={12}>
                                       <Button type="primary" size="large" shape="circle" danger icon={<DeleteOutlined />} onClick={() => deleteSkid(index)} />
                                     </Col>
                                  </Row>}
                               </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Divider />
                      </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
        )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insertSkid` function appears to be adding another reference to an already existing `skid` object to the list. Since your list contains multiple references to the same object, modifying at one index is going to effect all indexes since they all point to the same object.

If your intent in `insertSkid` was to insert a *clone* of the existing skid object, you'll want to use something like an object spread:

```
const insertSkid = skidToClone => {
  setSkidList(skidList.concat([{ ...skidToClone }]));
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jacob. If there's anything I can help with, don't hesitate to ask.